# Фикс бага в выпадающем меню HTML

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, помогите, пожалуйста. Делаю меню с выпадающими списками и возникла такая ситуация: В меню "Зимние виды" есть подменю, когда наводишь на "Зимние виды" оно открывается, но когда хочешь открыть подменю "другие виды", убираешь курсор с "Зимние виды" и подменю пропадает, соответственно курсор уходит за пределы главного меню и оно тоже закрывается. Заранее спасибо.

```css
#yw1 {display:none;
flex-direction:column;
position:absolute;
z-index:10;
background-color:#000;
border: 2px solid #ffc500;
} 
#yw1 li {
padding:5px;
margin:5px;
z-index:10;
} 
#yw0 li:hover #yw1{display:flex;} 
#yw1 li:hover #yw2{display:flex;} 
#yw2 {
display:none;
position:relative;
justify-content:flex-end;
z-index:2000;
background-color:#000;
border: 2px solid #ffc500;
} 
#yw2 li {
padding:5px;
margin:5px;
z-index:2000;
}
#yw0 li:hover #yw1{display:flex;}
#yw0 {margin-bottom:1000px;}
```

```html
<ul id="yw0">
<li><a class="" href="#">Спорт</a>
<ul id="yw1">
<li><a href="#" class="">Футбол</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="">Хоккей</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="">Баскетбол</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="">Единоборства</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="">Спортивные шоу</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="">Экстримальный спорт</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="">Автоспорт</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="">Танцевальный спорт</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="">Зимние виды</a>
<ul id="yw2">
<li><a href="#">Лыжи</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Сноуборд</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#" class="">Другие виды</a>
<ul id="yw2">
<li><a href="#" class="">Волейбол</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="">Пляжный волейбол</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="">Велоспорт</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="">Теннис</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно убрать `margin` у `#yw1 li`

```css
#yw1 {display:none;
flex-direction:column;
position:absolute;
z-index:10;
background-color:#000;
border: 2px solid #ffc500;
} 
#yw1 li {
padding:5px;
//margin:5px;
z-index:10;
} 
#yw0 li:hover #yw1{display:flex;} 
#yw1 li:hover #yw2{display:flex;} 
#yw2 {
display:none;
position:relative;
justify-content:flex-end;
z-index:2000;
background-color:#000;
border: 2px solid #ffc500;
} 
#yw2 li {
padding:5px;
margin:5px;
z-index:2000;
}
#yw0 li:hover #yw1{display:flex;}
#yw0 {margin-bottom:1000px;}
```

```html
<ul id="yw0">
<li><a class="" href="#">Спорт</a>
<ul id="yw1">
<li><a href="#" class="">Футбол</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="">Хоккей</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="">Баскетбол</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="">Единоборства</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="">Спортивные шоу</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="">Экстримальный спорт</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="">Автоспорт</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="">Танцевальный спорт</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="">Зимние виды</a>
<ul id="yw2">
<li><a href="#">Лыжи</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Сноуборд</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#" class="">Другие виды</a>
<ul id="yw2">
<li><a href="#" class="">Волейбол</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="">Пляжный волейбол</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="">Велоспорт</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="">Теннис</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```